# WriteConsoleOutput using a Dynamic Array

Tags: delphi, console

I've written this small program to demo WriteConsoleOutput. As long as I use a Static array everythings works fine.

but if I change the declaration of CI

From

```
CI: array of array of CHAR_INFO;
```

To

```
CI: array [0 .. 80, 0 .. 25] of CHAR_INFO;
```

and of course initializes it :

```
  SetLength(Ci, 80, 25);
```

Then I only get rubbish out on the screen.

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.Console,
  System.Diagnostics,
  System.SysUtils;

var
  CH: THandle;
//  CI: array of array of CHAR_INFO;
  CI: array [0 .. 80, 0 .. 25] of CHAR_INFO;
  Character, Attribute: Integer;
  X, Y: COORD;
  z: SMALL_RECT;
  i, j: Integer;
  StopWatch: TStopwatch;

begin
  CH := CreateFile('CONOUT$', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

  X.X := high(CI) - low(CI);
  X.Y := high(CI[high(CI)]) - low(CI[high(CI)]);
  Y.X := 0;
  Y.Y := 0;
  z.Left := low(CI);
  z.Top := low(CI[low(CI)]);
  z.Right := high(CI);
  z.Bottom := high(CI[low(CI)]);

  StopWatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;

  for Character := 65 to 65 + 26 - 1 do
    for Attribute := 0 to 15 - 1 do
    begin
      for i := low(CI) to high(CI) do
        for j := low(CI[i]) to high(CI[i]) do
        begin
          CI[i, j].UnicodeChar := Char(Character);
          CI[i, j].Attributes := Attribute;
          CI[i, j].AsciiChar := AnsiChar(Character);
        end;

      WriteConsoleOutput(CH, @CI, X, Y, z);
    end;

  StopWatch.Stop;
  Console.Title := StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString;
  Console.ReadLine;
end.
```

Ps. the example uses 
[DelphiConsole](https://github.com/JensBorrisholt/DelphiConsole)

**UPDATE**

With the answer given from MBo I changed my code to the following:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.Console,
  System.Diagnostics,
  System.SysUtils;
var
  CH: THandle;
  CI: array of CHAR_INFO;
  Character, Attribute: Integer;
  X, Y: COORD;
  Z: SMALL_RECT;
  i, j: Integer;
  StopWatch: TStopwatch;
begin
  CH := CreateFile('CONOUT$', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  X.X := 80;
  X.Y := 25;
  Y.X := 0;
  Y.Y := 0;
  Z.Left := Y.X;
  Z.Top := Y.Y;
  Z.Right := X.X;
  Z.Bottom := X.Y;
  SetLength(CI, X.X * X, Y);

  StopWatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;

  for Character := 65 to 65 + 26 - 1 do
    for Attribute := 0 to 15 - 1 do
    begin
      for i := 0 to X.X * X.Y do
      begin
        CI[i].UnicodeChar := Char(Character);
        CI[i].Attributes := Attribute;
        CI[i].AsciiChar := AnsiChar(Character);
      end;

      WriteConsoleOutput(CH, CI, X, Y, Z);
    end;

  StopWatch.Stop;
  Console.Title := StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString;
  Console.ReadLine;
end.
```

Comment: A dynamic array of array is not organized as a static array of array. Thus it is not suitable for WriteConsoleOutput.

Comment: Also mind that your static array has 81 columns and 26 rows while your dynamic array has 80 columns and 25 rows.

Comment: Hmmm... `array of array of` is a **dynamic** array, while `array[...] of` is a **static** array. And `SetLength` only works on dynamic arrays. So I don't quite understand the first few paragraphs of your question. Others have already told you about dimensions and how these kinds of arrays are different.

Comment: Note that a console window doesn't have to be 80x25. In my case, it never is. So better read the size and use a one-dimensional dynamic array and SetLength.

Comment: The 80x25 was just a place to start :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static array occupies continuous memory region, and `@CI` argument is address of the array contents.

But dynamic array is already **pointer**, so `@CI` is address of pointer to data, not address of data. For using of 1D dynamic arrays in similar cases, one might use `@A[0]` trick.

But moreover - 2D dynamic array doesn't occupy continuous memory region, so you have no chance to use it here.

But you can repack 2D data in 1D dynamic array of length `80*25` and use mentioned syntax. Expression for screen element at row y and column x is `CI[y * screenwidth + x]`